# TYPO3 - Performance drop accessing a record with a large number of records (> 1 million)

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I developed an extbase extension with list and detail view (list and show action). For the links to look nice I'm using realurl ...

```
<f:link.action action="show" pageUid="43" arguments="{record:record.uid}">{record.name}</f:link.action>

domain/?tx_abc_abc[record]=1&tx_abc_abc[action]=show&tx_abc_abc[controller]=Abc&cHash=10c78febea3ae5dsdf535fb36ca6d08

domain/category/record_id/
```

But with the number of records now reaching over 1 million records I'm experiencing a bit of a performance drop accessing the detail page. I also have 2 languages.

What can I do to stop performance drop or increase performance?

In some setups I see that accessing a record is implemented like this:

```
domain/category/?record_id=DE00ABC03709
```

Is this done by a JSON View / (RESTful) API like this? https://usetypo3.com/json-view.html

Comment: There may many factors, you can check your model `record` properties, how many of them have `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage`? and also check the caching of the detail page, and your server configurations.

Comment: Are you using the `findAll()` method of your domain repository to render *all* entities in the list view? In that case you might consider using a pagination to reduce the amount of data retrieved from database and rendered as HTML. A better alternative would be indeed to reduce the HTML overhead used to wrap each entity and only retrieve data via AJAX as JSON - rendering could be done with data-binding such as e.g. Angular or e.g. RivetJS which is a light-weight implementation just for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Does your performance drop always occur? or is it cache dependend? is your cache big enough to cache all detail pages?

Do a cache test:

1. clear cache,
2. request all detail pages with increasing ID (as these requests are uncached all pages should be at the same speed, full rendering with filling the cache),
3. then request detail pages with decreasing id (now all pages should show a faster response as only the cached page should be returned). If your cache is to small at some id all following request should show the slower response from 2.

In general:
For big data it is (more) important to have an index-key on the field you select the records.
I'm wondering about your hex id in your example as TYPO3 usually uses only decimal integers (field `uid`, which is an index-key normaly).

Anyway you can use other fields as selection, especially as part of the url (e.g. the title field for news). Then an additional index-key may be helpful for big data.